# Date in CV in English

Tags: pdftex, datetime

I'm translating my CV from Finnish to English. How can I change the date when I compile the file? It says 19. tammikuuta 2012 in Finnish.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{\textsc{CURRICULUM VITAE}}}

\today
\end{center}
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question you pose, but you may want to change the instruction `\textsc{CURRICULUM VITAE}` to `\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}` -- the command `\textsc` does nothing to the shape of letters already set in uppercase.

Answer (score 6):

Use `babel` with the `english` option:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```